# Using LEFT OUTER JOIN with SQL PARTITION function (multi tenant db)

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I have the following database schema.

**Profile [Table]**

```
pKey (auto)  
pgKey ('Group' foreign key to separate tenants)  
pProfile (the string data to return)
```

**HistoryData [Table]**

```
hisKey (auto)  
hispKey (foreign key to Profile)  
hisgKey (foreign key to 'Group')  
hisData (the string data to return)
```

The count of Profiles for one tenant is 24,874
`SELECT COUNT(p.pKey) FROM Profile p WHERE pgKey = 318`

The count of HistoryData rows that I care about (SeveranceFinal) is 16,591
(**10 profiles have 2 rows, rest of the rows are a 1 to 1 relationship**)
`SELECT COUNT(h.hisKey) FROM HistoryData h WHERE h.hisgKey = 318 AND h.hisType = 'SeveranceFinal'`

If I write a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.pKey) 
FROM Profile p INNER JOIN HistoryData h ON p.pKey = h.hispKey
WHERE p.pgKey = 318 AND h.hisType = 'SeveranceFinal'
```

The count value is **again** 16,591.

If I write this outer join query:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.pKey) 
FROM Profile p LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
  SELECT * FROM HistoryData WHERE hisType = 'SeveranceFinal' 
) h ON p.pKey = h.hispKey
WHERE p.pgKey = 318
```

The count is as expected 24,884 (**10 more than count of Profile records because of the 10 people with two rows of data in HistoryData**).

The problem I have is that I need to return **all Profiles** along with any matching SeveranceFinal rows, **but only** the *last* SeveranceFinal row for anyone that has it.  The count should match the original count of Profiles since I would always have 0 or 1 SeveranceFinal rows joined to Profile rows.  I've tried this query, but it never completes, it always times out.  I feel like I must be doing something wrong (*remember that the database is multi tenant and there are millions of rows in the Profile table, but with different `pgKey` values*)

```
SELECT COUNT(p.pKey) 
FROM Profile p LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT hispKey, hisData FROM (
            SELECT hispKey, hisData, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hispKey ORDER BY hisIndex DESC) RowID 
            FROM HistoryData WHERE hisgKey = 318 AND hisType = 'SeveranceFinal' 
        ) t WHERE RowID = 1
    ) h ON p.pKey = h.hispKey
WHERE p.pgKey = 318
```

What is wrong with the query?

**Notes:**
1. If I just run the `h` portion of this query `SELECT hispKey, hisData FROM ( ... ) t WHERE RowID = 1` that is 'immediately' returned.
2. If I change the LEFT OUTER JOIN to and INNER JOIN, it completes immediately and returns the correct value of 16,581 (**10 less than count of SeveranceFinal rows because of the 10 Profiles that have 2 rows**)

Here is the suggested index from the execution plan:

```
/*
USE [RBL_Profile]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[HistoryData] ([hisType],[hisgKey])
INCLUDE ([hispKey],[hisIndex])
GO
*/
```

Here is the displayed execution plan:

[image]

But here are my indexes on the tables already:

** Profile Table **

```
IX_Profile - nonclustered, unique located on PRIMARY: pAuthID, pgKey
IX_Profile_Group - nonclustered located on PRIMARY: pgKey
nc_Profile_GetProfiles - nonclustered located on PRIMARY: pgKey, pAuthID
```

** History Table **

```
IX_HistoryData - nonclustered, unique located on PRIMARY: hisType, hispKey, hisIndex
IX_HistoryData_Profile - nonclustered located on PRIMARY: hispKey
PK_HistoryData - nonclustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY: hisKey
```

Should I follow SQL's suggestion?

**Update**: I did apply the suggested index without any benefit it seems.  Query still times out (or I killed it after 30 seconds)

Here is new plan:

[image]

Here is the plan in Xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.1" Build="10.50.4000.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" StatementSubTreeCost="0.0179336" StatementText="SELECT COUNT(p.pKey) &#xD;&#xA;FROM Profile p LEFT OUTER JOIN &#xD;&#xA; ( &#xD;&#xA;        SELECT hispKey, hisData FROM (&#xD;&#xA;            SELECT hispKey, hisData, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hispKey ORDER BY hisIndex DESC) RowID &#xD;&#xA;           FROM HistoryData WHERE hisgKey = 318 AND hisType = 'SeveranceFinal' &#xD;&#xA;      ) t WHERE RowID = 1&#xD;&#xA;   ) h ON p.pKey = h.hispKey&#xD;&#xA;WHERE p.pgKey = 318&#xD;&#xA;" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0xFF065B887470862B" QueryPlanHash="0xC85BCB9BD79F6735">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="32" CompileTime="5" CompileCPU="5" CompileMemory="536">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="1.1E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0179336">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
              </OutputList>
              <ComputeScalar>
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1013],0)">
                      <Convert DataType="int" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Identifier>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1013" />
                          </Identifier>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </Convert>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="1.1E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Stream Aggregate" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0179336">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1013" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <StreamAggregate>
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1013" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="Count(*)">
                          <Aggregate AggType="countstar" Distinct="false" />
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="4.18E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Left Outer Join" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0179325">
                      <OutputList />
                      <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                        <Predicate>
                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[RBL_Profile].[dbo].[Profile].[pKey] as [p].[pKey]=[RBL_Profile].[dbo].[HistoryData].[hispKey]">
                            <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Profile]" Alias="[p]" Column="pKey" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hispKey" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Predicate>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="1371980">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Profile]" Alias="[p]" Column="pKey" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                            <DefinedValues>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Profile]" Alias="[p]" Column="pKey" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                            </DefinedValues>
                            <Object Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Profile]" Index="[nc_Profile_GetProfiles]" Alias="[p]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                            <SeekPredicates>
                              <SeekPredicateNew>
                                <SeekKeys>
                                  <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                    <RangeColumns>
                                      <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Profile]" Alias="[p]" Column="pgKey" />
                                    </RangeColumns>
                                    <RangeExpressions>
                                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(318)">
                                        <Const ConstValue="(318)" />
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </RangeExpressions>
                                  </Prefix>
                                </SeekKeys>
                              </SeekPredicateNew>
                            </SeekPredicates>
                          </IndexScan>
                        </RelOp>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="4.8E-07" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Filter" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Filter" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.014645">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hispKey" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <Filter StartupExpression="false">
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="19" EstimateCPU="8E-08" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="5" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sequence Project" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0146445">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hispKey" />
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <SequenceProject>
                                <DefinedValues>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" />
                                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="row_number">
                                      <Sequence FunctionName="row_number" />
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                </DefinedValues>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="19" EstimateCPU="2E-08" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Segment" NodeId="6" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Segment" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0146444">
                                  <OutputList>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hispKey" />
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hisIndex" />
                                    <ColumnReference Column="Segment1012" />
                                  </OutputList>
                                  <Segment>
                                    <GroupBy>
                                      <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hispKey" />
                                    </GroupBy>
                                    <SegmentColumn>
                                      <ColumnReference Column="Segment1012" />
                                    </SegmentColumn>
                                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="22" EstimateCPU="0.000100022" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Sort" NodeId="7" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sort" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0146444">
                                      <OutputList>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hispKey" />
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hisIndex" />
                                      </OutputList>
                                      <MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1" />
                                      <Sort Distinct="false">
                                        <OrderBy>
                                          <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                                            <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hispKey" />
                                          </OrderByColumn>
                                          <OrderByColumn Ascending="false">
                                            <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hisIndex" />
                                          </OrderByColumn>
                                        </OrderBy>
                                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="22" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="8" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="29897300">
                                          <OutputList>
                                            <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hispKey" />
                                            <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hisIndex" />
                                          </OutputList>
                                          <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                            <DefinedValues>
                                              <DefinedValue>
                                                <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hispKey" />
                                              </DefinedValue>
                                              <DefinedValue>
                                                <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hisIndex" />
                                              </DefinedValue>
                                            </DefinedValues>
                                            <Object Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Index="[IX_HistoryData_Group]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                                            <SeekPredicates>
                                              <SeekPredicateNew>
                                                <SeekKeys>
                                                  <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                                    <RangeColumns>
                                                      <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hisType" />
                                                      <ColumnReference Database="[RBL_Profile]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[HistoryData]" Column="hisgKey" />
                                                    </RangeColumns>
                                                    <RangeExpressions>
                                                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="'SeveranceFinal'">
                                                        <Const ConstValue="'SeveranceFinal'" />
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(318)">
                                                        <Const ConstValue="(318)" />
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                    </RangeExpressions>
                                                  </Prefix>
                                                </SeekKeys>
                                              </SeekPredicateNew>
                                            </SeekPredicates>
                                          </IndexScan>
                                        </RelOp>
                                      </Sort>
                                    </RelOp>
                                  </Segment>
                                </RelOp>
                              </SequenceProject>
                            </RelOp>
                            <Predicate>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Expr1007]=(1)">
                                <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Const ConstValue="(1)" />
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </Compare>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Predicate>
                          </Filter>
                        </RelOp>
                      </NestedLoops>
                    </RelOp>
                  </StreamAggregate>
                </RelOp>
              </ComputeScalar>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: Can you take a look at and post the estimated execution plan? My initial thought is that it doesn't have the information available to complete the join in a timely fashion. You could test this by moving your derived table `h` into a temp table, and indexing the `hispKey` column, so it will have information available when doing the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you try more set query:

```
WITH FilteredHistoryData AS (
    SELECT hispKey, hisIndex
    FROM HistoryData
    WHERE hisgKey = 318 
        AND hisType = 'SeveranceFinal'
)

SELECT p.pKey, h.hisIndex LatestIndex
FROM Profile p
LEFT JOIN FilteredHistoryData h
    ON p.pKey = h.hispKey
LEFT JOIN FilteredHistoryData h_fresher
    ON h.hispKey = h_fresher.hispKey
    AND h_fresher.hisIndex > h.hisIndex
WHERE h_fresher.hispKey IS NULL
    AND p.pgKey = 318
```

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this query.  I did some testing and it seems to work in my preliminary tests, but I can't figure out what it's doing.  I edited the query to SELECT values which is what I will be doing.

Comment: Can you explain the query a bit.  If I want the 'last' something, is this strategy better than Row_Number()/partition?  Handful of places I should change if the improvement is always going to be this good.

Comment: It is set approach, I'm joining set with larger values, and seek elements with empty join, so there is no larger elements. I do some experiment on [AdventureWorks2017].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] and row number has half time to do it, so in this case is better. My solution is more rank() than rownumber().

Comment: Interesting, because  my query with ROW_NUMBER 'never' finishes.  And yours finishes in 0.3 secs.